Checking two distinct lists with AND operation on same column
I have the following example data structure of customer that can be part of multiple groups using a junction table and data:
CREATE TABLE customer(id) AS VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3);
CREATE TABLE groups(id)   AS VALUES (1),(3),(5),(6);
CREATE TABLE customers_to_groups(customer_id, group_id) AS
  VALUES (0, 1)--customer 0 is in group (5 OR 6) AND (1 OR 3)
        ,(0, 5)--customer 0 is in group (5 OR 6) AND (1 OR 3)
        ,(1, 1)
        ,(1, 90)
        ,(2, 1)
        ,(3, 3)--customer 3 is in group (5 OR 6) AND (1 OR 3)
        ,(3, 5)--customer 3 is in group (5 OR 6) AND (1 OR 3)
        ,(3, 90);

I need to get customers that have specific groups they are part of, and I need to get a list of all customers that are part of at least 1 group in multiple lists of group. For example I want to get all customers that are in group (5 OR 6) AND (1 OR 3), so for example a customer in group 5 and 1 wold be a returned, but somebody in group 1 and 90 or just group 1 not. With the provided sample data we would get the customer of id 0 and 3 only as they conform to the given rules above.
Just doing WHERE group_id IN (5,6) AND group_id IN (1,3) does not seem to work, so I am looking for alternative.
I got this so far that works:
SELECT DISTINCT c.id
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customers_to_groups at1 ON c.id = at1.customer_id
INNER JOIN customers_to_groups at2 ON c.id = at2.customer_id
WHERE at1.group_id IN (5, 6)
  AND at2.group_id IN (1, 3);

Expected Results:



id




0


3



Is there a way to do it that is more performant?

Added more context ^^

Sample data is great, but can you also specify the expected result?

Updated it there, so with the new sample data, I would receive 2 rows, one with customer ID 0 and one with customer 3, as customer 0 is part of group 5 and 1, and customer 3 is part of 3 and 5.
Customers might have extra group we just ignore them here like customer 3 having an extra group 7

Can you edit and add the result as properly formatted text. (Rows and columns, you know.)

Done @jarlh Thanks for bearing with me ^^

Great code sample, but I think you are using group_id 6 and 7 interchangeably

So, in the example I used group 7 on propose to show that its one not in the list of any of the two lists. I could of chosen 20, 90 or 8 I did chose 7 at random maybe not the best due to proximity of 7.

In the example, we have customer 3 part of gorup 3, 5, 7 and it should return that customer as that customer is in gorup 3 or 1, and is also part of groups 5 or 6. I don't care about extra gorups in this case.

I can update the question with other number so its easier to see. Let me do that, will update it to 90

We can GROUP BY customer's id and use a HAVING clause. There we can use CASE or FILTER if your RDBMS supports it. Postgres should.
There your conditions will be set.
The query will be:
SELECT c.id 
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customers_to_groups ctg
  ON c.id = ctg.customer_id
  AND ctg.group_id IN (1,3,5,6)
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ctg.group_id IN (1,3) THEN 1 END) > 0
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN ctg.group_id IN (5,6) THEN 1 END) > 0;

or
SELECT c.id 
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customers_to_groups ctg
  ON c.id = ctg.customer_id
  AND ctg.group_id IN (1,3,5,6)
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE ctg.group_id IN (1,3)) > 0
  AND COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE ctg.group_id IN (5,6)) > 0;

Note: Above queries assume you really need to include both customers and customers_to_groups table and join them. If you don't need to include the customers table, just remove it and select from the table customers_to_groups only to improve the performance:
SELECT customer_id
FROM customers_to_groups ctg
WHERE ctg.group_id IN (1,3,5,6)
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE ctg.group_id IN (1,3)) > 0
  AND COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE ctg.group_id IN (5,6)) > 0;

This demo with your sample data and a lot of additional rows shows the performance differences.
Using FILTER or CASE is far faster (as it avoids a second JOIN on the table customers_to_groups). The exact performance difference depends on the real data in your tables and which index(es) you use.

Accepting this as an answer, but thanks all for the answers for anyone in the future if you are using Postgress and want dynamic @Charlieface answer is perfect.
Again thanks all, I have upvoted all answers ^^

Also, as mentioned if you do not need customer data, you can just remove the use of customer that would look like @rahul-jangid and @ jarlh's answer

Do a GROUP BY, use HAVING clause to make sure both at least one of (5, 6), and at least one of (1, 3) are there.
SELECT customer_id
FROM customers_to_groups
WHERE group_id IN (5, 6, 1, 3)
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MAX(group_id) >= 5
   AND MIN(group_id) <= 3;

You can also use INTERSECT:
SELECT customer_id FROM customers_to_groups WHERE group_id IN (5, 6)
INTERSECT
SELECT customer_id FROM customers_to_groups WHERE group_id IN (1, 3)


You can achieve the desired result with a more optimized query by using a GROUP BY and HAVING clause. This approach avoids the need for multiple self-joins
SELECT customer_id
FROM customers_to_groups
WHERE group_id IN (5, 6, 1, 3)
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN group_id IN (5, 6) THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN group_id IN (1, 3) THEN 1 END) > 0;

Index Consideration:
To further improve performance, ensure that you have an index on the customer_id and group_id columns in the customers_to_groups table:
CREATE INDEX idx_customer_group ON customers_to_groups (customer_id, group_id);


This is a problem of Relational Division with the twist that you have multiple divisor. What you have is not bad in terms if efficiency.
But if you want to be able to do this dynamically, and pass in differing numbers of groups and blocks of groups, then you need a different solution.
You can pass it in as a JSONB array parameter
SELECT
  cg.customer_id
FROM customers_to_groups cg
JOIN jsonb_array_elements('[[5,6],[1,3]]'::jsonb) sections(value)
    ON cg.group_id IN (SELECT value::int FROM jsonb_array_elements(sections.value))
GROUP BY
  cg.customer_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(jsonb_array_length('[[5,6],[1,3]]'::jsonb));

Alternatively, if you have the input data in a table, you can use full Relational Division
SELECT
  c.id
FROM (
    SELECT
      c.id,
      COUNT(cg.group_id) AS count_matches
    FROM customer c
    CROSS JOIN input_groups ig
    LEFT JOIN customers_to_groups cg
        ON cg.group_id = ig.group_id
       AND cg.customer_id = c.id
    GROUP BY
      c.id,
      ig.section_id 
) c
GROUP BY
  c.id
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE count_matches = 0) = 0;   -- all sections have a match

db<>fiddle

if this task is a repetitive one, you can put it in a function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customers_by_groups(group_set1 int[], group_set2 int[])
RETURNS TABLE(customer_id int) AS $f$
    SELECT c.id
    FROM customer c
    INNER JOIN customers_to_groups ctg ON c.id = ctg.customer_id
    GROUP BY c.id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ctg.group_id = ANY(group_set1) THEN 1 END) > 0
       AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ctg.group_id = ANY(group_set2) THEN 1 END) > 0;
$f$ LANGUAGE sql;


Why not plain LANGUAGE sql or just a prepared statement? There's no need for PL/pgSQL overhead.

@Zegarek seems like you not a fan of good old psql?

Inlining. If you have no need for exceptions, loops and anything else plpgsql offers on top of plain sql, you're potentially making things slower for no reason by picking language plpgsql over lanugage sql. What's the client got to do with this?

fair enough, this is crystal clear, I am sure the performance might be 2ms faster. Thank you @Zegarek

My point is that if you recommend this sort of function-wrapping and do that yourself sometimes, using pl/pgsql by default is bad practice due to the potential performance loss. With proper indexing, most statements here already run in about 0.1ms on 100k+100k+300k samples, so if the 2ms was meant to be cynical, you overshot a bit making it a very welcome 20x speedup

Since customer_id is likely a foreign key to customer.id meaning that both tables hold the same value, I don't see a reason to reach for customer at all.
A very SQL standard way of doing this is using INTERSECT already suggested by @jarlh:
SELECT customer_id FROM customers_to_groups WHERE group_id=any('{1,3}')
INTERSECT ALL
SELECT customer_id FROM customers_to_groups WHERE group_id=any('{5,6}');

ALL keyword skips deduplication that's default behaviour of INTERSECT (DISTINCT).
You could also run a self-join:
SELECT customer_id 
FROM customers_to_groups a
JOIN customers_to_groups b
USING (customer_id)
WHERE a.group_id=any('{1,3}')
 AND  b.group_id=any('{5,6}');

And if you like @Rahul jangid's and Jonas Metzler's having idea, the condition you're looking for simplifies to a bool_or():
SELECT customer_id 
FROM customers_to_groups
WHERE group_id=any('{1,3,5,6}')
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING bool_or(group_id=any('{1,3}'))
   AND bool_or(group_id=any('{5,6}'));

Or you can use an EXISTS:
SELECT customer_id 
FROM customers_to_groups a
WHERE group_id=any('{1,3}'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT FROM customers_to_groups b
              WHERE a.customer_id=b.customer_id
              AND group_id=any('{5,6}') );

In this db<>fiddle test with 19 000 customers with 1 900 000 random assignments to some of 19 000 groups, the EXISTS variant wins the quickest plan with a Hash Semi Join.
All of these are best served with a covering index enabling index-only scans:
CREATE INDEX ON customers_to_groups (group_id)
  INCLUDE(customer_id);

If you intend to re-use that dynamically, wrap it in a paremeterised prepared statement:
PREPARE customers_in_groups(int[],int[]) AS
SELECT customer_id 
FROM customers_to_groups a
WHERE group_id=any($1)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT FROM customers_to_groups b
              WHERE a.customer_id=b.customer_id
              AND group_id=any($2) );

Then
EXECUTE customers_in_groups('{1,3}','{5,6}');

